# XSLT ERROR: Cannot Convert Zero-Length String into Integer, Batch Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am Trying to run a batch transformation on about 100 XML files to convert them into CSVs. Some of the files do not contain a value for a certain variable that I am using, Therefore I am getting the error mentioned. Is there a way in XSLT to bypass this or to continue running even if the length of the value is Zero? Can I put a dummy value if the length is zero? I have looked on SO and other forums and couldn't find anything useful. Also I am new to XSLT so I may not be knowledgeable enough to figure it out on my own. Below is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2017-10-16">
    <Record userId="1898739" username="50019019" termId="5923" dmd:surveyId="17683692">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="COLLEGE" entryKey="College of Engineering" text="College of Engineering"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="Civil, Architectural, &amp; Environmental Engineering" text="Civil, Architectural, &amp; Environmental Engineering"/>
        <INTELLCONT id="151368386560" dmd:originalSource="MANAGE_DATA" dmd:lastModified="2017-10-03T10:47:54" dmd:startDate="2016-01-01" dmd:endDate="2016-12-31">
            <REFEREED>Yes</REFEREED>
            <CONTYPE>Journal Article</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER/>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Sample data</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="151368386563">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="151368386561">
                <FACULTY_NAME>1898739</FACULTY_NAME>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <PUBLISHER>sample</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME>13</VOLUME>
            <ISSUE>11</ISSUE>
            <PAGENUM>117</PAGENUM>
            <WEB_ADDRESS/>
            <DOI>sample</DOI>
            <ISBNISSN/>
            <PMCID/>
            <AUDIENCE/>
            <PUBLICAVAIL/>
            <ABSTRACT/>
            <FULL_TEXT/>
            <DTM_EXPSUB/>
            <DTD_EXPSUB/>
            <DTY_EXPSUB/>
            <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
            <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
            <DTM_SUB/>
            <DTD_SUB/>
            <DTY_SUB/>
            <SUB_START></SUB_START>
            <SUB_END></SUB_END>
            <DTM_ACC/>
            <DTD_ACC/>
            <DTY_ACC/>
            <ACC_START></ACC_START>
            <ACC_END></ACC_END>
            <DTM_PUB/>
            <DTD_PUB/>
            <DTY_PUB>2016</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2016-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2016-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>
        <INTELLCONT  dmd:originalSource="IMPORT" dmd:lastModified="2017-10-03T11:17:33" dmd:startDate="2016-01-01" dmd:endDate="2016-12-31">
            <REFEREED>Yes</REFEREED>
            <CONTYPE>Journal Article</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER/>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Sample</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756225">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756226">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756227">
                <FACULTY_NAME>1898739</FACULTY_NAME>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756228">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756229">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756230">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>sample</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756231">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756232">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756233">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756234">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756235">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <PUBLISHER>sample</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME>23</VOLUME>
            <ISSUE/>
            <PAGENUM>2003-2013</PAGENUM>
            <WEB_ADDRESS/>
            <DOI>sample</DOI>
            <ISBNISSN/>
            <PMCID/>
            <AUDIENCE/>
            <PUBLICAVAIL/>
            <ABSTRACT/>
            <FULL_TEXT/>
            <DTM_EXPSUB/>
            <DTD_EXPSUB/>
            <DTY_EXPSUB/>
            <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
            <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
            <DTM_SUB/>
            <DTD_SUB/>
            <DTY_SUB/>
            <SUB_START></SUB_START>
            <SUB_END></SUB_END>
            <DTM_ACC/>
            <DTD_ACC/>
            <DTY_ACC/>
            <ACC_START></ACC_START>
            <ACC_END></ACC_END>
            <DTM_PUB/>
            <DTD_PUB/>
            <DTY_PUB>2016</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2016-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2016-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>
    </Record>            <!-- Added by edit -->
</Data>                  <!-- Added by edit -->
```

In this example all of the DTY_PUB tags have a value, however, not all of the XML files have a value for it. Below is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dm="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"
    xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:key name="Contype-Year" match="dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR='Yes']" use="concat(dm:CONTYPE, '|', dm:DTY_PUB)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input-doc" select="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="min-year" as="xs:integer" select="min(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:DTY_PUB/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="max-year" as="xs:integer" select="max(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:DTY_PUB/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="categories" select="distinct-values(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:CONTYPE)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="years" as="xs:integer*" select="$min-year to $max-year"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$years" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$categories">
            <xsl:variable name="cat" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="for $y in $years return count(key('Contype-Year', concat($cat, '|', $y), $input-doc))" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The line it is breaking on is:

```
<xsl:variable name="min-year" as="xs:integer" select="min(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:DTY_PUB/xs:integer(.))"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an additional check `<xsl:variable name="min-year" as="xs:integer" select="min(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:DTY_PUB[. castable as xs:integer]/xs:integer(.))"/>`.